# Azure deployment deletes configuration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I have configured a new .Net core application with CI/CD trough azure devops. I use the configuration tab in the application in azure to set settings - like token secrets, for example. However, every time the CI/CD deploys a new version, those settings are erased and I have to set them again.
Does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you can "stop" this from happening. The deployment of an application includes appication settings.

What you can do is to get your CI/CD pipeline to set the settings correctly. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/managing-configuration-app-settings-for-multiple-environments-in-your-cd-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

Just want to through out another alternative to this is to have the secrets stored in a [Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) and if deploying your App Service via an ARM template the secret values can be referenced to those stored in a key vault. [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597936/azure-key-vault-access-from-arm-template/59380562#59380562) as a starting point.

Best practice would be the App Service is configured for [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) and granted an access policy to a Key Vault where the secrets or connection strings are stored. This would lead to a more decoupled and reusable architecture.  On App Service deployment the secrets will be grabbed from Key Vault and inserted into the App Settings.  This type of deployment would work ideally with static keys.

If your keys could potentially changes there are methods to check Key Vault for a new password.

I will call out that this type of implementation will shift the secrets being wiped out from every time the app service is being deployed to every time the Key Vault is deployed.