# Get Service Principle ID from ARM Template

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, service-principal

Is it possible to get the `ServicePrincipleID` via an ARM Template? The examples I am seeing is I need to use some PowerShell to get it then inject it in as a parameter, is this still the case? Ultimately, I am trying to get the `ServicePrincipleID` of an AD App and then assign it to an instance of KeyVault.

Comment: this is not possible, like the existing answer suggests - you need to get the `service principle` object guid somewhere externally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get Service Principle ID from ARM Template

It seems that you could not get service principle id from ARM template. You could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/19766863-ability-to-retrieve-principal-id) to promote this features to be achieved.

Comment: The link to the feedback item is not relevant to this.  The feedback item is requesting the ability to retrieve the principle ID of the user deploying an ARM template, not of an application that exists in AD.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Managed Service Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)  Here is a link to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59367901/8446413) on how to accomplish this via ARM. Would have to pass in the name of the app service though

```
 "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('webSiteName')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]"
```